# JavaScript terminology: do I (call / invoke / execute) a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, functional-programming

Is there a difference to the mentioned verbs which are used in relation to functions ?

Initially, I thought they mean the same thing and people use it interchangeably. Now, I am not 100% sure. I feel that there is a chance I might be missing important piece of information when trying to understand code-related content. I also take a lot of notes, and I haven't been thinking much how to use those terms.

If I was to answer a million-dollar question on the differences between the three I would say:

- 'function was **invoked**' - function has been triggered but does not
  necessarily returned results
- 'function was **executed**' - function has been triggered and returned
  result
- 'function was **called**' - function has been triggered within a function
  (hence we use term 'callback')

The above is just my gut feel. If someone asked me to explain some of my code line by line, I don't know which verbs would I use to describe it. I would probably randomize between the three to feel smart.

I tried to research this terminology but couldn't find any relevant information. Help much appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, in the context of functions those words all mean the same thing. (Note that all JS functions return a result, though sometimes that result is the value `undefined`.)

Comment: Invoked when sounding smart. Executed when describing the process. Called when being realistic. And this question is not JavaScript centric.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks ! Didn't realize that all functions return a result. What I meant was rather function not having an explicit return statement.

Comment: These days asynchronous functions often also return a result - a promise or a then-able object.

Comment: You'll also hear the term *apply* - eg, `f(x)` "*apply* function `f` to argument `x` (ref: [Apply](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply) and [Function application](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_application)) I think this is the most generic/correct way to describe the action of "running" a function

Answer (score -1):

I haven't come across a standard definition that everyone uses for those three terms, most would just use them interchangeably.

My interpretation is that 'executed' is a function that has finished its execution, 'invoked' and 'called' are functions that are in the process of executing.

That is just my preference though you will find many different opinions on this.